# CPU Utilization Stress Test

Tags: performance, cpu, stress-testing

I am looking for a Windows/Mac app that can stress CPU Utilization.

I know that there are Prime95 and IntelBurst, but those are go to CPU Utilization 100% quickly.

What I am searching is a tool that I can set CPU Utilization 10%, 20%, 30% ... 100%.

Please share your thoughts/Ideas.

Thank you,

Comment: Questions asking for a software are off-topic here. This should be asked at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a script like the following, which calls usleep every so often to prevent maximal CPU usage, while still providing some stress.

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    long i;
    int stress = 10;
    while (1) {
        for (i = 0; i < (1L << stress); i++) { }
        usleep(1);
    }
}
```

Just increase `stress` to raise the CPU usage.